# Modding Laravel 5.1 Custom Packge Classes to Enable Auto Completion and Hints

Tags: php, laravel

I wrote a basic package for augmenting ldap into laravel
it can now parse subschema do searchs and generate ldif entries,my problem is
 this package is driver based as in 
when you create you first instance from the manager the front class
i do like this

```
$driver=new ldapman('openldap')->getDriverInstance();
```

or in Larvel 5.1

```
$man=app('Ldapman',['drivername'=>'openldap']);
$driver=$man->getDriverInstance();
```

and that's lead to constructer like this,

```
public function __construct( $driver,$type='driver')
{
    $drivername=ucfirst($this->drivername);
    $drivername.=$type;
    $this->driverArray[$type]=null;

    if(file_exists(__DIR__."/driver/$drivername.php"))
    {
        include_once(__DIR__."/driver/$drivername.php");
        $drivername="\\Chromax\\Ldapman\\driver\\".$drivername;
        if(isset($config)&&!is_null($config))
        {
            $this->driverArray[$type]=new $drivername($this->config);

        }else{

            $this->driverArray[$type]=new $drivername();
        }

        if($this->driverArray[$type] instanceof $drivername)
        {

        }else{
            throw new \Exception("201 Class Not Found");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new \Exception("200 Driver Not Found");
    }

}
```

this approach is fine and it helps me well but when i sent this package to a friend who was costumed to auto completion he had a hard time working with it
so i want to mod it to support completion

```
 notice : my IDE is PHPSTROM
```

Comment: So refactor it as a Laravel Package so it fits in the vendor folder and fits with the whole Laravel package paradigm [See manual](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/packages)

Comment: my main problem that laravel use type hinting extensively and i use constructors Alot , may they both work together but i don't know how??

Comment: [The manual for type hinting/Function References](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) only watch out as PHP7 has added quite a few to the allowed list.

Comment: i tried but i could not wrap my head around it any help is appreciated !!!

Comment: Then you have to keep trying.